# Translate dependant on content size

Tags: html, css, hover

I've recently created a project container that has a `translate` hover effect to show the body text on hover.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/road_twisty_turn_129164_3840x2160.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transform: translatey(300px);
  padding: 20px;
}

.container:hover .text {
  transform: translatey(240px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>project name</h1>
    <p>body copy will be here and hidden untill hovered.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue that I'm facing, is that the text translate position varies depending on the amount of content I want to write.

I want to make it so that when I hover over the div, the content will always show in the same position no matter how much text I have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use absolute positioning instead of translation. Absolute positioning has the advantage of being able to set the bottom of the content.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/road_twisty_turn_129164_3840x2160.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   position:relative;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  position:absolute;
  top:300px; bottom:auto;
  padding: 20px;
 }
 
.container:hover .text {
  top:auto; bottom:0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>project name</h1>
    <p>body copy<br>will be<br>here and<br>hidden until<br>hovered.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>project name</h1>
    <p>body copy will be here and hidden until hovered.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```